# Create directx9 texture using a portion(s) of an image

Tags: c++, directx, textures

i have an image(208x8) and i would like to copy 8x8 squares from it at different areas then join all the squares to create one IDirect3DTexture9*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do IDirect3DDevice9::UpdateSurface or IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect might help you.

For simple operations on very small textures like you are describing, it can be advantageous to manipulate them using the CPU (i.e. with IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect). With D3D9 this usually implies that the texture be re-uploaded to VRAM, so it is generally only useful for small or infrequently modified textures. But sometimes if you are render-bound and you are careful about where you update the texture within your loop, it's possible to hide the cost of operations like this and get them "for free".

To avoid the VRAM upload, you can use a POOL_MANAGED resource combined with the appropriate usage and lock flags to situate the resource within the AGP aperture which allows for high-speed access from both the CPU and GPU, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418784(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are manipulating on the CPU, be aware of the tiling and alignment restrictions for the various texture formats. The best information about this is within the documentation that comes with the SDK (includes several whitepapers), the online documentation is incomplete.

Here's a basic example:

```
IDirect3DTexture9* m_tex = getYourTexture();
m_tex->LockRect(0, &outRect, d3dRect, D3DLOCK_DISCARD);

// Stride depends on your texture format - this is the number of bytes per texel. 
// Note that this may be less than 1 for DXT1 textures in which case you'll need 
// some bit swizzling logic. Can be inferred from Pitch and width.
int stride = 1; 
int rowPitch = outRect.Pitch;
// Choose a pointer type that suits your stride.
unsigned char* pixels = (unsigned char*)outRect.pBits;
// Clear to black.
for (int y=0; y < d3dRect.height; ++y)
{
    for (int x=0; x < d3dRect.width; ++x)
    {
        pixels[x + rowPitch * y] = 0x0;
    }
}

m_tex->UnlockRect(0);
```

Comment: any chance of an example loading an image and lockrect then operating on it then unlockrect ?

Comment: Updated with a basic example.

Comment: So how do you stitch the bits back together?  I don't see a D3DLOCK_RECT -> Texture function...

Comment: Create your new dest texture (the target for your stitching) and memcpy to it from the source textures similar to the example above i.e. instead of just setting the val 0x0 as above, you would read from your source texture buffers. Or set it as the backing texture for a render target and render the other textures directly to it.